# Why does my desktop get all distorted and hard to read?

Tags: debian, desktop

Hello I am running Debian Jessie. Whenever My computer is working hard my screen gets all distorted and hard to read. Is there a way to fix this problem. I am using an I-INC screen. Here are some pictures.[image]

[image]

Comment: Which video card do you have?  Which driver (and which version) are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what is the easiest way to find this out

Comment: As root, run `lspci -nn -k`.  Then copy the section for your video card (likely VGA compatible controller).  Note: List PCI devices (lspci), show device names and numbers (-nn), show kernel drivers.

Comment: @Steven 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:29c2] (rev 02) Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0238] Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: It could be the problem with hardware acceleration. By intensive, does it mean playing videos on browser? Can you try disabling hardware acceleration?

Comment: I have disabled hardware acceleration on my browser! I guess we'll have to wait and see...

Comment: @VanagaS Doing this doesn't seem to make very much of a difference.